# How to copy objects in the vector list to another vector list?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I like to copy the object of first vector to second vector but when i delete the second vector , the first vector content should not changed.
How can i do this?

CODE:

```
typedef vector<CLog*> CLogData;

CLogData CMultiThreadedDlg::CopyLogData()
{
CLogData logdata;
for(size_t i = 0; i < m_pThreadInfo->GetLog().size()-1; ++i)
{
  CLog* plog = new CLog(*m_pThreadInfo->GetLog()[i]);
  logdata.push_back(plog);
}
return logdata;
}

DeleteData(logdata); 

void CMultiThreadedDlg::DeleteData(CLogData tLogData)
{
for(size_t i = 0; i < tLogData.size()-1; ++i)
{
    CLog* log = (CLog*)tLogData[i];
    delete log;
}

tLogData.clear();
 }
```

The problem in my code is that while deleting second vector the first vector namely              **m_pThreadInfo->getLog()** content also deleted..

How to overcome this?

EDIT:

```
     CLog::CLog()
     {
        m_threadname = new char[20];
     }
     CLog::~CLog()
     {
           delete[ ] m_threadname;
     }
```

If i use CLog as parameter to vector list ..how can i delete this..

Thanks...

Comment: Is this the real code? because it doesn't compile. BTW, how is the copy constructor of `CLog` class implemented? it does a deep copy?

Comment: this is real application ..I just pasted my functionality here...

Comment: I assume you meant `typedef vector<CLog*> CLogData;`, not `vector<CLog*> CLogData;`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, man. There are some serious problems in that code of yours.

First, you have

```
class CLog
{
    char* m_threadname;

public:

    CLog()
    {
        m_threadname = new char[20];
    }

    ~CLog()
    {
        delete[ ] m_threadname;
    }
};
```

It's C++ and the year is 2011, please don't do that. And if you do that, don't claim performance as a reason. Instead, do this:

```
class CLog
{
    std::string m_threadname;
};
```

See!

Second, you copy vectors with pointer elements aand act surprised when the first vector's elements are gone when the second vector's elements are deleted. It's the same element, you know. The vector is just a container, not an owner. You, as a programmer, own the elements. The vector just holds them.

You can use

```
typedef vector<shared_ptr<CLog>> CLogData;
```

To solve your problem. Or, preferrably

```
typedef vector<CLog> CLogData;
```

which is even better until proven otherwise. You haven't given a good reason why that's a bad idea.

Use the stack, it's your friend.

**Edit:**

Furthermore, you need to get your references in order. In

```
void CMultiThreadedDlg::DeleteData(CLogData tLogData)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < tLogData.size()-1; ++i)
    {
        CLog* log = (CLog*)tLogData[i];
        delete log;
    }

    tLogData.clear();
}
```

you pass vector **copy** to `DeleteData` and the copy will be `.clear()`-ed, not the original. Can be dangerous, if it hangs around and you think it has valid pointers, which it hasn't.

Comment: Is it possible to hold one lakh record in vector<CLog> ?

Comment: @karthik: Sorry, I can't follow you. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

By having `vector<CLog*>`, the program is just getting unnecessarily complicated. I suggest you to use `vector<CLog>` instead of `vector<CLog*>`. With that modification, you need not worry about explicitly deleting the content of vector. You can just use assignment operator to copy the elements of one vector to another.

---

<s>On your comment on assignment operation of a vector -</s>

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    foo obj(10) ;

    vector<int> a(5), b(5) ;
    for( int i=0 ; i<5; ++i )
        a[i] = i ;

    b = a;  // Assignment 

    cout << b[2] << "\t" << a[2] << "\n";

    b[2] = 25;

    cout << b[2] << "\t" << a[2] << "\n";

    return 0 ;
}
```

Output :

> 2  2
>   25 2

See that modifying vector `b` is not affecting `a`. So, your comment isn't correct that assignment operation modifies the other vector too if the type is `CLog`.

Since an the class has an element `char*`, assignment operation doesn't do a deep copy. Use `std::string` instead.

Comment: Sorry i have to use in many classes and many files...so i need to use CLog* and moreover If we use CLog and use assignment operator then change in one vector affect the content of another vector..

Comment: AFAIK, Access to many files has nothing to do with `CLog*`?  Assignment (`=`) operation copies the content of one vector to another. So, there is no affect on the other vector if one vector is getting modified. Try a very simple program and see it.

Comment: Inside CLog class i am using two char * variables namely threadname and message ...how can i delete this?

Comment: Mostly avoid usage of raw pointers. Use `std::string` instead.

Comment: Try to give the solution for CLog*...for the last chance  i will use your logic....Help for CLog* issue